# k8s: Error when creating CronJob chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've a question about helm validation of `resources` field in `CronJob` chart , any help welcome.

I use apiVersion batch/v1beta1

I get error when I try to retrive values from values.yaml

The error : `` Error: error validating "": error validating data: found `invalid field requests for v1.Container ``

Command I run : `helm install --dry-run --debug my_chart`

my CronJob chart as following:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
spec:
  schedule: "0 */2 * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
     ...
     spec:
  containers:
    ...
     spec:
       resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
```

Error disapierd when I change the resources configuration to

```
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 300m
        memory: 1024Mi
```

I don't like the last change and I'd like to follow my regular configuration guide and store values in values.yaml

cluster version are

`Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.4", GitCommit:"9befc2b8928a9426501d3bf62f72849d5cbcd5a3", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-11-20T05:28:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

`Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8+", GitVersion:"v1.8.4-gke.0", GitCommit:"04502ae78d522a3d410de3710e1550cfb16dad4a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-11-27T19:19:56Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

helm versions are :

`Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.7.0", GitCommit:"08c1144f5eb3e3b636d9775617287cc26e53dba4", GitTreeState:"clean"}`

`Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.7.0", GitCommit:"08c1144f5eb3e3b636d9775617287cc26e53dba4", GitTreeState:"clean"}`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Indent by 14 spaces (instead of 12) and remove the additional `spec` property in your container definition.

---

Mind the correct indentation in your YAML definitions. For example, the `containers` property needs to be a sub-property of the CronJob's `spec.jobTemplate.spec.template` property (with `spec.jobTemplate` being the *template* for a [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.9/#job-v1-batch) object (or a [JobTemplate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.9/#jobtemplatespec-v1beta1-batch)), and `spec.jobTemplate.spec.template` then being the *template* for that Job's [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.9/#pod-v1-core) object (or a [PodTemplate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.9/#podtemplate-v1-core)).

Furthermore, the [Pod's `containers` attribute](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.9/#podspec-v1-core) does not require an additional `spec`. Have a look at the API reference for the respective objects (linked above) for the exact specification of these object types.

For a CronJob, this is how the Helm template should look like (again, indentation is important!). Also, note that in this case, the `.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.resources.requests` property needs to be indented by **14 spaces, and not 12**.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
spec:
  schedule: "0 */2 * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          # ...
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: foo
            # ...
            resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 14 }}
```

---

Regarding the error you've received: With an indentation of 12 spaces (`indent 12`), Helm will create a YAML definition for your job similar to the following:

```
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: foo
            # ...
            resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 300m
              memory: 1024Mi
```

As you can see, the `requests` property (intended to be a sub-property of the `resources` property), is now actually a property of the [Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.9/#container-v1-core) definition. However, the Container resource does not have a field called `requests`, resulting in the error message:

> Error: error validating "": error validating data: found `invalid field requests for v1.Container